# Converting a TXT file to PDF from the command line using a custom font

Tags: text-processing, pdf, text, conversion

I want to convert a UTF-8 txt file to PDF for printing with CUPS. The problem I'm facing is that all tools I've tried have either failed to format the PDF (resulting in a fully white document with no text) or ignored font options. I have also tried converting my text file to PostScript 1st (as suggested in some previous answers to similar topics) but have faced issues with then printing the PostScript files with the added fonts.

What I have tried:

[text2pdf](http://www.eprg.org/pdfcorner/text2pdf/) (creates blank document when custom font specified)

[unoconv](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/) (fails to run with network error)

LibreOffice CLI (no font parameters)

[enscript](https://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) (initial PostScript conversion works however when then printing that PS or converting it to PDF the font reverts to courier)

[paps](https://paps.sourceforge.net/) (PostScript conversion succeeds but font parameter seemingly ignored as file is the same regardless of what font you specify or whether or not it exists)

[pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) (font options ignored)

Comment: You can try txt2pdf (a CLI tool coming with weasyprint, available on pypi). The font has to be specified in a CSS file).

Comment: @user3435121 This did it, thank you so much, I've been pulling my hair out for about a day trying to get this to work without a GUI, my script is functional now. You've saved the day!